# javascript window.open not opening different windows for different urls?

Tags: javascript

I have window.open with extra parameters that is opening the given url in a new window. But when I invoke this window.open with different url every time, it is not opening a new window as long as the first window is open.
How can we open multiple windows for multiple urls? Thank you!

```
    var newWindow = window.open(url,
            "New window",
            "toolbar=no," +
            "scrollbars=no," +
            "location=no," +
            "statusbar=no," +
            "menubar=no," +
            "width=600," +
            "height=300," +
            "left=800," +
            "top=300," +
            "resizable=no"
        );
```

Comment: assign a different name to each window in order to display them in separate popups: `"New window0", "New window1", "New window2", etc.`

Comment: Thank you. It solved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a different value each time or `_blank` for the `windowName` parameter.

```
var newWindow = window.open(url,
            "_blank",
            "toolbar=no," +
            "scrollbars=no," +
            "location=no," +
            "statusbar=no," +
            "menubar=no," +
            "width=600," +
            "height=300," +
            "left=800," +
            "top=300," +
            "resizable=no"
        );
```